# How can I change the text colour in this script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the colour of the text displayed to white, however, I have no idea how to go about this, could anyone be so kind to assist me?

Code:

```
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 22, 2017 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "Days " + hours + "Hours "
  + minutes + "Minutes " + seconds + "Seconds ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

PS I'm a noob and this code is from W3.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, and we expect a certain standard of questions. For one thing, we require people to do a little [research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+color+text+css&t=lm&atb=v72-6&ia=web) before asking for help. You should also read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

> [CSS Styles Using JavaScript](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/setting_css_styles_using_javascript.htm)

Every HTML element that you access via JavaScript has a style object. This object allows you to specify a CSS property and set its value.

```
 document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
```

Comment: Link only and code only answers are not in line with [SO philosophy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If you're going to answer a low-quality question like this (which you shouldn't do in the first place), at least provide an explanation of what you did.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder I added a brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do this but the simpliest one is just setting one CSS inline parameter. Like this:

```
<p id="demo" style="color: white;"></p>
```

And that makes the magic. :)

Definitly check this -> https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: An Aside: Inline CSS is generally considered bad practice. It muddies the water so to speak, and because of that maintenance in the future may become more difficult. If this isn't just a one off project it's best to add this in as commented JS, or even better, within a CSS stylesheet.